# Convert Restaurant Menu Data into json

Tags: json

format of data i have-

```
Beverages
    Coffee -
        Cafe Latte
            Hot         90
            Iced        120
                Vegan-       50
                    Soy Milk     () 
                    Coconut Milk () 
        Cafe Mocha
            Hot         100
            Iced        130
                Vegan-       50
                    Soy Milk     () 
                    Coconut Milk () 
        Cafe Cappucinno      
            Hot         90
            Iced        120
                Vegan-       50
                    Soy Milk     () 
                    Coconut Milk () 
        Cafe Zenzero        100
            Vegan-       50
                Soy Milk     ()
                Coconut Milk () 
        Cafe Americano       50
        Cafe Espresso        50
```

How can i convert this restaurant menu data into json

i was able to to make this much but dont know how to categorize:

```
{
   "Beverages":{
      "Coffee":{
         "Cafe Latte":{
            "Hot":{
               "price":90
            },
            "Iced":{
               "price":110
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

is there a better way to do this? am i doing this wrong, I'm very new to this

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to help get you started:
Beverages should be an array of beverage objects. Each beverage would be an object and have various attributes such as *name*, *price*, *options*, etc. If there are multiple options, the value of the attribute should be an array of objects as well.

I would recommend looking up a lesson on object though to further solidify your understanding.

```js
const beverages = [
 {
    name: 'Cafe Latte',
    category: 'coffee',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'Hot',
        price: 90,
      },
      {
        name: 'Iced',
        price: 120,
      },
    ],
    additionalOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Vegan',
        price: 50,
        options: [
          {
            name: 'Soy Milk',
          },
          {
            name: 'Coconut Milk',
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
];
```